# NSIS' uninstaller works very fast

Tags: nsis

I have no idea how to say it short for title, but
When I run uninstaller generated by NSIS in silent mode, it detaches from main process and do its work in the background.

This is good, but when installer run `ExecWait uninstaller` first, it finish instantly, but doesn't uninstall application actualy. As a result, installer tries to replace executable file that executed, but not closed by uninstaller yet. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
The NSIS uninstaller copies itself to the temporary directory, runs the temporary uninstaller created and then exits. This is done so it will be able to delete itself.
You can disable this system using the following command line parameter:

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" _?=$INSTDIR'
```

You will, of course, have to replace uninstall.exe with the name of your uninstaller.